# AWS Cognito login using preferred_username

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I have created a user pool with username and email as signing options. I want to sign using email instead of username. If I login using email need to pass username also. please find below code for sign-in.

```html
var authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails({
        Username : 'user@email.coma',
        Password : '4E4RLkjh6@3ko',
    });

    var userData = {
        Username : 'hd8234fws32-43saaa',
        Pool : userPool
    };
    var cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);
    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails....
```

Is there any way to sign in using email without username.

**basic requirement is using cognito pool to manage users and user can change their email address any time.**

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change congito user pool signin setting. For more information see [aws congito documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html).

Here is specific information to your query from aws cognito documenatation...

To configure a user pool for sign-in with an alias.

1. Go to the Amazon Cognito console. If prompted, enter your AWS
   credentials.
2. Choose Manage User Pools.
3. In the top-right corner of the page, choose Create a user pool.
4. In the top-left corner of the page, choose Attributes.
5. In the Attributes tab, under How do you want your end users to
   sign-in?, select Username, and then choose one of the following
   options:
6. Also allow sign in with verified email address: Allows users to sign
   in with their email address.
7. Also allow sign in with verified phone number: Allows users to sign
   in with their phone number.
8. Also allow sign in with preferred username: Allows users to sign in
   with a preferred username. This is a username that the user can
   change.
9. Choose Next step to save, and then complete all the steps in the
   wizard.

Comment: This is only for creating a new user pool, is there a way to edit an existing one to allow users to sign in with email?

Comment: Unfortunately, no! AWS mentioned this [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html#user-pool-settings-aliases).